# Immediately editing a editable UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview

I'm using the standard mechanism for enabling an editable `UIWebView` (the `contenteditable` attribute in the `div` tag).

Everything is great - when I load my view, the `UIWebView` loads, and when I click, I go into edit mode.

However, what I want to do is that when my view loads, to go into edit mode immediately and have the cursor start at the beginning of the `div`.

Does anyone know how to do this? I tried using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to call a JS method in my HTML that does a `.focus()` on the `<div>` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that it is related that programmatically launching keyboard is disabled in Safari. By default, UIWebView doesn't allow either programmatically launching the keyboard. However, you can enable this functionality from the Swift side when you create the UIWebView. Just set `keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction` to `false`.

See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction) for more information

Note: I didn't test this and `contenteditable` might have other problems too, but this is the common problem when developing mobile web apps.

Comment: Thanks! That was an important part of it. I'll mark your answer though and fill out a more complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out how to make this work thanks to Teemu's hint. I had to do the following:

First, as Temmu mentioned, I had to set `keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction` to `false` in my `viewDidLoad`.

Second, assuming that my editable content was in a `<div id="content">...</div>`, I injected the following Javascript **after** the `div`:

```
<script>document.getElementById('content').focus();</script>
```

With these two things in place, when my view loaded, `UIWebView` immediately placed focus in the `div` and the keyboard popped up.

Comment: Thank you! This was plaguing me for a straight week. And to think it all because of a simple stupid property, which none of the related SO answers covered.